# To get all children and parent using id MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table named `group` and i want to get all childrens and parents by using specific id:

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group_tbl` (
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


INSERT INTO `group_tbl` (`group_id`, `group_name`, `parent_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Test', 0),
(2, 'Test1', 1),
(3, 'Test3', 2),
(4, 'Test4', 3),
(5, 'Test5', 3),
(6, 'Test11', 4);
(7, 'Test12', 0),
(8, 'Test34', 8);
```

if i pass 3,outpur would be

```
(1, 'Test', 0),
(2, 'Test1', 1),
(3, 'Test3', 2),
(4, 'Test4', 3),
(5, 'Test5', 3)
(6, 'Test11', 4);
```

How can i get using single query or store procedure or any php function?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: depth is not specific...its any

Comment: Why there will be such output, if you pass `3`??? Do you want all children and all parents???

Comment: I don't think that this is possible using this structure of array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990529/mysql-how-to-find-all-ids-of-children-recursively

Comment: @Legionar: Yeah i need all level children and parent. it is my requirement and why does it matter?

Comment: If you pass `3`, then children names will be `Test4`, `Test5` and `Test11` and parent name will be `Test1`. There is no sense of your example with `3`...

Comment: @Legionar: sorry,it will include Test11 too

Comment: ? So it will return all records??? Check your example - its the same as your sample data...

Comment: but if i add one more row with parent 0,it will not return all

Comment: No one has answer but all are ready to minus vote on stack overflow

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `group_tbl` g1 JOIN `group_tbl` g2 ON g1.id=g2.parent_id WHERE g1.id = 3
```

Comment: not working as it is i need records only matched with id 3 where it is giving all records